# Can the administrator download/mirror everyone's email from Google Apps for Business?

Tags: email, google-workspace, backup

Does Google Apps for Business provide a way to download all emails from all accounts periodically? The format of the download is not important. We'd just not want to set something up for each individual user.

Our 20-employee company is considering using Google Apps for Business as our email solution, but management requires that we also keep local backup copies of all sent and received email.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 options:

1. If you are signed up for the free edition (up to 10 people), configure a local e-mail client (Outlook, Thunderbird, Apple Mail, or whatever else) to [fetch messages from GMail via POP](http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=105694).
2. <del>If you are signed up for Google Apps for Business (paid edition), it comes with [Postini archiving services](http://www.google.com/apps/intl/en/business/security_discovery.html), which give admins full access to email archives.</del> ([The integrated version of Postini is no longer available](https://support.google.com/a/answer/77049).)

Comment: Neither of these will work well. The free version of Postini does *not* come with the archiving, just filtering (and it's not a local backup). Additionally, the local client will require having the password for each user, and if they change it you're sunk.

Answer (score 1):

There are some very good services from Google for accomplishing user auditing on all Google services. Google basically stores stuff in an Atom feed that lets you play back changes.

This will help you get access to all data on any Google service how you requested it: [Admin APIs](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/admin-apis)

But if you are interested in real auditing tool, I recommend the [Vault](http://support.google.com/vault/answer/2462365). Which is an extra 5 USD per month (total 10 USD per user account per month on the domain, and all users must be enabled for the vault).

There are other Google apps applications available on the Market that make use of the vault, or you can code your own.

Answer (score 0):

Backupify.com will backup your Google Apps accounts automatically every day, and you can download copies of their backups locally. It's not free, but it's an easy service to setup.

https://www.backupify.com/google-apps-backup

Additionally, I hope you're securing these local backups safely and encrypting them, so someone malicious can't easily get access to all of your company's email in one location.

Answer (score 0):

As administrator you can use OAuth to access any account from Google APIs, with this you don't need account passwords.