# Automatic forwarding of Google Apps mail

Tags: gmail, google-workspace, google-apps-email

How can I ensure that any mail received or sent via our Google Apps domain, is automatically forwarded on to the domain administrators mailbox?

Comment: Related: [Can the administrator download/mirror everyone's email from Google Apps for Business?](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/22734)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider [Google Apps Vault](https://support.google.com/vault/answer/2462365). It lets you specify retention rules for your domain in a legally compliant way.